# Why calling DetachCurrentThread() causes excessive garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-native-interface, detach

I'm calling Java methods from C code. Every time call is made I call AttachCurrentThread and after call is made I call DetachCurrentThread.

This works fine but the problem is that I see eccessive garbage collection caused by that i.e. almost every call via JNI. VisualVM graph on minor collection is basically all green! The rate of calls from native code to Java is hundreds per second. During that calls also I can see excessive number of Java threads being created like Thread-34543, Thread-34544, Thread-34545 etc. which is probably reason of GC. It looks like each call is done through different thread.

Anyone have seen this?

Just to add to that when I don't DetachCurrentThread there is no GC at all but Thread view in VisualVM shows hundreds of threads attached to VM. Any tips?

JVM settings

-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333

Platform:
Ubuntu 12.04
Linux 3.2.0-35-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 17:42:16 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Java:

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

UPDATE 2013-03-30

I think my problem lies somewhere else.
I printed out IDs of threads and it looks like only few threads are calling my JNI code.
Last run showed 13 threads. The thing is that when run

```
if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) == JNI_OK)
    return env;
else
    return NULL;
```

to get JNIEnv* associated with current thread I get error code -2 (JNI_EDETACHED). Just to be clear I do not call DetachCurrentThread at all, as I'm expecting those threads to come back to my  native library.
In that case I attach native thread again which causes probably excessive Thread abject creating in JVM.
Last run shows

```
 29 [478e](get_env) Thread 2633996032 has env: (nil), err was: -2
 47 [478e](get_env) Thread 2642388736 has env: (nil), err was: -2
 32 [478e](get_env) Thread 2650781440 has env: (nil), err was: -2
 31 [478e](get_env) Thread 2659174144 has env: (nil), err was: -2
 37 [478e](get_env) Thread 2667566848 has env: (nil), err was: -2
 30 [478e](get_env) Thread 2675959552 has env: (nil), err was: -2
 32 [478e](get_env) Thread 2684352256 has env: (nil), err was: -2
 33 [478e](get_env) Thread 2760873728 has env: (nil), err was: -2
 33 [478e](get_env) Thread 2769266432 has env: (nil), err was: -2
 37 [478e](get_env) Thread 2777659136 has env: (nil), err was: -2
 36 [478e](get_env) Thread 2786051840 has env: (nil), err was: -2
 31 [478e](get_env) Thread 2794444544 has env: (nil), err was: -2
 52 [478e](get_env) Thread 3707176704 has env: (nil), err was: -2
```

where first column is number of calls where attached thread does not have valid env associated with it.
Any idea why is it happening?

Answer (score 6):

The `AttachCurrentThread` function attaches your *current* native thread to a JVM `Thread` object. It's needed because all operations within the JVM happen in the context of a thread (which is referenced on the C side in the `JNIEnv` object).

If your C code isn't multi-threaded, you don't need to call attach/detach; simply use the `JNIEnv` that you got from `JNI_CreateJavaVM`. If you have a limited number of C threads, then you can call attach when the native thread starts, and continue to use the same `JNIEnv` for the life of the thread (but you must attach *each* C thread). If you're creating lots of C threads, then you have no option: you have to attach each one.

I suspect that the "excessive" garbage collections are happening because the JVM uses thread-local allocation blocks: each Java thread is given a reserved area of Eden memory for its allocations (to prevent contention with other threads). When the native thread is detached, that TLA is eligible for collection (and, depending on how big the TLA is, you might just be filling Eden with them due to your short-lived attaches). You might be able to disable this behavior with `-XX:-UseTLAB`, but that will probably cause more problems than it solves (because the JVM would have to lock its internal state on each allocation).

**TLDR**: if you're not creating native threads, you don't need to constantly attach/detach.

---

*Edit in response to comment*

I'd suggest caching the `JNIEnv` pointer, and attaching/detaching on an as-needed basis. Assuming you're using PThreads, you can use [pthread_setspecific](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_setspecific.html) to associate the environment pointer to the current native thread. If your code gets called from a thread that does not have an environment pointer, call `AttachCurrentThread` and store the result with the thread.

When you do this, you'll also need to use a [thread cleanup handler](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cleanup_push.html) to call `DetachCurrentThread` when the native thread is about to die. Assuming that the library you're using doesn't do anything stupid with the cleanup stack, this should prevent a leak of Java `Thread` objects.

Comment: Explains a bit. In my case native threads are created outside my JNI library, so I cannot control number of those. I've noticed that when there is not much activity only 4-5 native threads are being used. It's only when here is heavy load number of threads grows. Strange thing is that VM does not try to reuse JVM Thread objects in any way. Also I've noticed that in my case the whole app works more efficiently when I don't detach. Obviously I need to detach sooner or later so I'm thinking about some sort of native thread manager that detaches threads that did not called VM code for some time.

Comment: Thanks parsifal. Please see my UPDATE for more details of what I've observed. Thanks for the tips on cleanup handlers and setspecific